# Use Objectify to retrieve entity group's metadata

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

How can I use Objectify to retrieve the entity group's [metadata](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/metadataqueries), specifically the `__version__` property?

I would like to use the `__version__` property to determine whether a transaction should retry. That's because "it is possible to receive a `DatastoreTimeoutException` or `DatastoreFailureException` even when a transaction has been committed and will [eventually](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Java_Transactions_and_entity_groups) be applied successfully."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing special in Objectify to manage this field, but if you create a field like this it should get populated with the version number:

`@IgnoreSave long __version__;`

That's two underscores on each side.